# Can I root a proprietary Lenovo Talbet of Vodafone?

Tags: rooting

I dont remember the series but I want to root a tablet at work.

I think its the A 5000 or H 5000 something like that but i cant seem to be able to find a rooting method and also if something cant be rooted cant i just install a custom ROM on it ? and have SU privileges ?

Comment: You'll have to find out (and [edit] your answer to include) exactly what model/series the device is before anyone is able to help you. It is possible/likely that the method of rooting will vary for different devices.

Answer (score 2):

what is your android version ?
you can test this apps :
kingo root
framaroot 
or Vroot ,
and or Cf-Autoroot :
check this link , but if your tablet doesnt exist on the list ,
reply to me for other methods.
http://autoroot.chainfire.eu/
regards.